# Rendering doesn't work on my project, although it used to worked well

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, objects

I am new to blender and I was working on the Donut Tutorial project provided by Blender Guru on Youtube. I reached level 6 part 1 of the project (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZTxBrjN1ugA&t=682s). I was working fine and cycles or evee rendering could be switched with no problems. However, I don't remember exactly what I did in the "Compositing" section. But when I went back to my "Lay out", the object doesn't look (cycles) rendered although it should. I tried to switch back and forth between evee and cycles render but nothing happened.

Moreover, the base colours also disappear from all the objects in my project. But somehow when I F12, the image was rendered perfectly with colour as nothing happened. I had tried to do the entire project again but this time rendering ( and base colour) doesn't work from the very beginning. So I thought I did something wrong with the program and decided to uninstall Blender and redownload the most recent one, but that doesn't work too. I hope some would kindly answer this as soon as possible so that I could continue the project.

Comment: Hello :). Perhaps you just switched viewport shading. It's a simple toggle, search this site for related answers.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I can keep going on :))